# Too many mounted filesystem

Tags: filesystems, unmount

How to umount this cgroup?

Also i have no idea is it important or not. It seem cgroup is comefrom docker but im still not sure.

I was trying install gns3-remote

And it give me cgroup like this.

Then i deleted gns3-remote because it's for fresh vps not my private vps.
I dont need it anymore. Also im still not sure if i clearly remove it

Is it okay keep this cgroup? Im just annoying seeing this filesystem too much. I just want look my vps fresh like just born[image]

Comment: please try to do some research before asking anything, 2 minutes of asking google could have provided you this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df -h`  will hide pseudo file systems, including cgroup, leaving only file systems with a size. Note from the man page what all means:

```
-a, --all
       include pseudo, duplicate, inaccessible file systems
```

Bonus tip: when using util-linux,  `mount -t xfs,ext4` will print only mounts of that type.  Adjust -t option to your desired file systems.

systemd units, containers, cgroups in general, per user temp directories, and tracing all make use of file systems. While confusing to see an expanding list of non-data file systems, they are useful. Easier to filter them  when querying, than to break your system trying to remove file systems.

Comment: Yes i didnt realize i was using df -ah. Thats why i wondered why it was less when last i seen. turns out i didnt put -a